# On Google's app engine (GAE), how can my server tell if it's the default version?

Tags: google-app-engine

On my Google AppEngine (GAE) server, I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (thisIsTheDefaultServer)
{
    // behave normally
}
else
{
    // Accept special test-commands, give extra output, etc.
}
```

is there a way for the server code to determine if it's the current default version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember hearing the Google App Engine team mention an API to retrieve anything from the dashboard. Unfortunately, I cannot find it at the moment. I think it might have been in this talk: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/life-in-app-engine-production.html

I did find one document referring on how to get this information exactly in Java. I did not have enough time to find the Python version.

For Java (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.html):

```
 if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
   // do something that's production-only
 }
 String version = SystemProperty.version.get();
```

Comment: While Nick is probably right that I might not want to do this, you actually answered the question asked so, once I test that it works (<G>), I'll accept this.  (Might not get there this week -- big deliverable coming up.)

Comment: For what it is worth, I agree with Nick as well. I have code that enforces admin and use that a lot. Even on special versions. In fact, for testing servers, we keep everything locked down to admin only. We use a patch file to change the settings when we want to switch to production. We also have default versions in our app.yaml files that will not deploy over our default production version to prevent fat fingering from taking out production.

Answer (score 5):

There's not currently any way to do this, but you might want to reconsider your requirements. Two alternatives spring to mind:

1. Switch on the hostname: If it's the bare appspot name or a custom domain name, you're serving as the default version. If it's a `version.app.appspot.com` name, you may or may not be the default version, but should probably enable the different behavior anyway.
2. Enable the extra behavior based on whether the user is logged in as an admin or not. This is probably a better idea all around: It makes it easier to debug your production app, and means regular users can't find the alternate version and see stuff they shouldn't.

Comment: Seconding nick's second alternative. Restricting to admin is also compatible with pushing special/experimental versions that you never indent to make default.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that -- would probably be logged in as test-account (vice admin), but I get what you mean.  As the information isn't sensitive, I just figured it'd be easier to go based on default vsn and, when client was pointed at non-default, we'd get some unit-test output but, when it got deployed, things would go to "normal."  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the available environment variables (for [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Environment) for [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Environment) )

`CURRENT_VERSION_ID` in the Python SDK contains the value specified in app.yaml, I think it's com.google.appengine.runtime.version for the Java runtine.

Comment: That doesn't help - it tells the current runtime what version it is, but not if it's the default version or not.