# Google App Engine: Can I programmatically find out if this is the default version?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is something to programmatically discover if the this request was for the default version, as opposed to another specific version set on the request. I thought there may be something like:

```
SystemProperty.isDefaultVersion
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Google's app engine (GAE), how can my server tell if it's the default version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725790/on-googles-app-engine-gae-how-can-my-server-tell-if-its-the-default-version)

Answer (score 2):

Use API provided by the new [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) functionality:

```
ModulesService modulesService = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();
String currentModuleName = modulesService.getCurrentModule();
String version = modulesService.getDefaultVersion(currentModuleName);
```

Comment: This can only be done in a request thread (not the boot/main thread), sadly.

Answer (score 0):

One not so full proof way you can get around this is by checking the URL. If it matches `X.name.appspot.com`, it probably isn't the default version. It might be, but it's definitely not a normal user accessing your page and therefore probably a development operation.

Far from perfect, but might be enough...